# Reodrering a massive sparse stiffness matrix

Tags: matlab, math, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have assembled a massive sparse stiffness matrix using its DOFs and some rules of assembly. In order to do an efficient Bragg scattering analysis, I would now like to reorder them based on 3 zones: Interior, Input, Output. Each zones are populated by identified DOFs.

After going through a lot of resources and trying to understand them fully, I´ve come to the conclusion that an reverse RCM must be used. Problem is I do not know anything about graph theory, and i´d like some help regarding this. The below code snipped is what i believe works to reorder the matrix (based in MATLAB):

1. Construct the adjacency matrix
   A = K ~= 0;
2. Perform RCM reordering on the adjacency matrix
   p_rcm = symrcm(A);
3. Create a permutation vector that orders nodes according to zones
   p_zone = [internal_nodes, input_nodes, output_nodes];
4. Combine the RCM permutation and zone-based permutation
   p_combined = p_zone(p_rcm);
5. Reorder the stiffness matrix according to the combined permutation vector
   K_reordered = K(p_combined, p_combined);

Could someone please let me know if this is right? If not, what is the correct method or logic? Any resources that points to the practical implementation of matrix reordering is more than welcome. Thanks a lot

I didn´t try anything as the matrices I´m trying to work on are based on 3D structures with each node having 3 DOFs. So the resulting matrices are massive (20x20x20 cube = 27783 rows and columns).

Comment: That's not massive.  Large problems have millions of DOF.  Why do you need the approval of SO to proceed?  The best confirmation would be to try it yourself and see if it works.   What do you do about boundary nodes that are in more than one group?  What if your grouping results in a wider bandwidth?  Could make your calculations more difficult.  Why must the grouping affect the stiffness matrix?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I tried to seek the help of SO because I have seen other questions that spoke about reordering/reassemblying matrices, but couldn´t find a solid reference about its implementation according to industry practices. None of the nodes/DOFs repeat in more than one group. I havent bothered too much about the bandwidth issue because the whole system is going to lose its interior and output nodes for eigenvalue calculations.